# Question on total ordering and lexicography

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let R1 be a total order on set S1 and R2 be a total order on set S2. Prove or disprove that the lexicographic order is a total order on S1 X S2.

So far I'm trying to start the proof with:
Let R1 be a total order on set S1,
 and R2 be a total order on set S2
If for every x,y that are elements of S1, we have x R1 y or y R1 x,
 and for every x,y that are elements of S2, we have x R2 Y or y R2 x.
Then...

Answer (score 1):

Take two arbitrary elements of $S1 \times S2, (a,b)$ and $(c,d)$  You want to prove that they are comparable.  Because $R1, R2$ are total, we know $a,b$ and $c,d$ are comparable.  From the definition of lexicographic order, if $a \neq b$ we use the comparison in $R1$ to order the pairs, else we use the comparison in $R2$ to order the pairs.  Now you have to show antisymmetry and transitivity, which you can do from the definition.

Comment: Transitivity isn't included in the proof for the original definition. Does that mean I still need to show it for this proof?

Comment: I'm also starting to get the impression that I haven't quite explained total ordering in this proof, as it seems to resemble the original partial order proof without any noticeable change. Is the difference in (a,b) and (c,d) rather than (a1,a2) and (b1,b2)?

Comment: All I seem to have done so far is include your statement about how the two (a,b) and (c,d) are comparable to the beginning, and tried to include the rest of the definition.

Comment: The definition of [total order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) that I am familiar with requires the relation to be antisymmetric, transitive, and that all elements are comparable.  We need to verify all of those for the new relation given that they are true for the two relations on $S1, S2$  I sketched how to get comparable.  For transitive, you need to pick three arbitrary pairs with the right comparisons to the middle one and prove the comparison of the end ones.  That depends a bit whether the first element  in the middle pair matches the first element in either of the end ones.

Comment: I sort of just tried to state that there is antisymmetry and transitivity on the total order R1 and R2, is that what you meant?

Comment: You are told there is antisymmetry and transitivity on R1 and R2. You have to show that they are true on your relation, based on what you know from R1 and R2.  So for antisymmetry you assume $(a,b) \le (c,d)$ and $(c,d) \le (a,b)$ The first clause of your definition says if $a \neq c$ and $a \le c$ then $(a,b) \le (c,d)$, so you can't have $(c,d) \le (a,b)$.  This shows $a=c$.  Now use a similar argument to show $b=d$ and you have shown your order is antisymmetric.

Comment: I've finished proving antisymmetry, how do I finish proving that the lexicographic is total order?

Comment: If you have two pairs and the first elements differ, your definitions says they are comparable and the direction respects R1. If the first elements are the same, your definition says you follow R2.  Either way you have an answer. To be a total order, you have to have an answer all the time.  Contrast with the order on the naturals where $a R b$ iff $a$ divides $b$.  $4$ and $6$ are not comparable, so this is at most a partial order.

Comment: It seems that antisymmetry, if proven to be true presumes that the set is a total order. If I have (a,b)=(c,d) then how is it not a total order for the whole set? The book doesn't seem to prove total order in an example for any Cartesian product.

Comment: My book says that, "A partial order R on set S is called a total order on S if every pair of elements in S can be compared-that is, if for every x,y (element of) S, we have x R y or y R x." Can I insert that somehow into my proof?

Comment: [Partial orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set#Formal_definition) are defined as antisymmetric, too. My divisibility example supports that.  If a divides b and b divides a then a=b.  The quote correctly says the only difference between a partial order and a total order is comparability, but we addressed that already.

Comment: I think I finished it, but there's no way to check if it's correct. I can try showing it to you right now and ask if there's any holes in the logic or anything.

Comment: R1 and R2 are total so (a,b) and (c,d) are comparable. Since they're antisymmetric, (a,b) <= (c,d) and (c,d) <= (a,b). Using condition (1), If a=/=c and a<=c then (a,b)<=(c,d), so you can't have (c,d)<=(a,b). Condition (1) applied to (c,d)<=(a,b) implies that c<=a. R1 is antisymmetric, so because a<=c and c<=a, a=c. This is contradictory to a=/=c. Thus a=c and condition (2) must apply. Applying (2) to (a,b)<=(c,d) implies that b<=d. Since R2 is antisymmetric, then b=d. But if a=c and b=d, then (a,b)=(c,d), proving that R is antisymmetric.

Comment: edit: (rest of proof) Iff for every x,y (element of) S, we have xRy or yRx the partial order is called a total order. Since (a,b)=(c,d), then (a,b)R(c,d), and (c,d)R(a,b). Therefore, the set is a total order.

Comment: You need to use the definition of your order to go from R1, R2 total to always comparable.  Then "since they're antisymmetric" doesn't prove the two relations you quote.  In fact, most of the time only one will hold.  Your proof does not use this sentence.  You are understanding the concept correctly, but the presentation is far from clear.  I suggest you explain it to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) and write up the result.

Comment: I need to sleep, I can try this tomorrow probably, or even show a tutor at school what I've written. I think I that I'll require some questions with the tutor to clarify what I'm trying to say.